# More broken older Qiskit code

Tags: qiskit

I am persuing some older code as below

```
ferOp = FermionicOperator(h1=molecule.one_body_integrals, h2=molecule.two_body_integrals)
...
qubitOp = ferOp.mapping(map_type='parity', threshold=0.000001)
qubitOp = qubitOp.two_qubit_reduced_operator(num_particles)
```

but am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WeightedPauliOperator' object has no attribute 'two_qubit_reduced_operator'
```

Any suggestions for how to fix. I am using qiskit version:

```
qiskit                             0.14.1
qiskit-aer                         0.3.4
qiskit-aqua                        0.6.2
qiskit-ibmq-provider               0.4.5
qiskit-ignis                       0.2.0
qiskit-terra                       0.11.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chemistry sample in the README on the qiskit-aqua repo shows how to do this now:

````
from qiskit.chemistry import FermionicOperator
from qiskit.chemistry.drivers import PySCFDriver, UnitsType
from qiskit.aqua.operators import Z2Symmetries

# Use PySCF, a classical computational chemistry software
# package, to compute the one-body and two-body integrals in
# molecular-orbital basis, necessary to form the Fermionic operator
driver = PySCFDriver(atom='H .0 .0 .0; H .0 .0 0.735',
                    unit=UnitsType.ANGSTROM,
                    basis='sto3g')
molecule = driver.run()
num_particles = molecule.num_alpha + molecule.num_beta
num_spin_orbitals = molecule.num_orbitals * 2

# Build the qubit operator, which is the input to the VQE algorithm in Aqua
ferOp = FermionicOperator(h1=molecule.one_body_integrals, h2=molecule.two_body_integrals)
map_type = 'PARITY'
qubitOp = ferOp.mapping(map_type)
qubitOp = Z2Symmetries.two_qubit_reduction(qubitOp, num_particles)
num_qubits = qubitOp.num_qubits

...
```
````